# Http status 404 - servlet login is currently unavailable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my login-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smart.control" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value></value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "Login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authenticateLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("hell");
    return "Login";

}
```

The servlet login is currently unavailable message is being displaying when submitting the form through post method.
Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: Please let me know if you want to see the jar files in my classpath...

Comment: Is this all right ? `@RequestMapping(value = "Login.html", method = **RequestMethod.POST**)`

Comment: your authenticateLogin() is not implementing any logic to provide authentication ?? that might be the reason

Comment: @TechExchange yes that is alright.

Comment: Please let me know what make you think that something is wrong here. You have not verbalized any question, exception or unexpected/expected behaviour.

Comment: Any exception in the server log?

Comment: @Ralph no there is no exception in the server log.